# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ Proof: prove $\lim_{x\to 0} f(\sin(x)+1) = 5$, if $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=5$

Tags: limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Suppose $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ and
$$\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=5.$$
I need to prove that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(\sin(x)+1)= 5$$
using only the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definitions of limits and continuity.

---

I have proved that $\sin{x}+1$ is continuous at $0$, which means $\lim_{x\to0}\sin{x}+1=\sin{0}+1=1$.
This gives me
$$
\forall\eta>0, \exists\delta>0\text{ such that }0<|x-0|<\delta\implies\left|\sin{x}+1-1\right|<\eta.
\tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
From $\lim_{y\to0}f(y) = 5$ I know that
$$
\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\eta>0\text{ such that }0<|y-1|<\eta\implies\left|f(y)-5\right|<\epsilon.
$$
Take $y=\sin{x}+1$ then
$$
\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\eta>0\text{ such that }0<|\sin{x}+1-1|<\eta\implies\left|f(\sin{x})-5\right|<\epsilon.
\tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
I want to combine equations \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2}, but then I need to prove that for the chosen $\delta$ neighbourhood of $x$,  $|\sin{x}+1-1|\neq0$, except at $x=0$.

I can't go any further from here.

---

Am I on the right track? Are there any errors in the rough work I have so far? How can I move on from this stage?

Comment: Sorry for the multi-edits; I would edit, and it would show the displayed equations as "broken". It appears to be a function of your labeling, which got fixed if I reloaded.

Comment: The usual definition of continuity has $|x-x_0|<\delta$, it allows for $x=x_0$. This makes everything line up.